# Error in WCF service value does not fall within the expected range

Tags: wcf, http-headers

In one of our code, we are getting below error.

```
at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
   at System.Web.Util.Misc.ThrowIfFailedHr(Int32 hresult)
   at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.SetUnknownRequestHeader(String name, String value, Boolean replace)
   at System.Web.HttpHeaderCollection.SetHeader(String name, String value, Boolean replace)
   at System.Web.HttpHeaderCollection.Add(String name, String value)
```

Code is as below:

```
public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
        {
            string correlationId = newAuditTrail.GetCorrelationIdFromRequest(request).ToString();
            string url = newAuditTrail.GetUrlFromRequest(request).ToString();

            HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers.Add("CorrelatinId", correlationId);
            HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers.Add("Url", url);
```

Error is thrown on line:

HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers.Add("CorrelatinId", correlationId);

I noticed operation contract of method, it is defined as oneway.

```
[OperationContract(IsOneWay=true)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add http header in the http request, please refer to the below code segements.

```
    public object BeforeSendRequest(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request,  System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel channel)
{
    HttpRequestMessageProperty httpRequestMessage;
    object httpRequestMessageObject;
    if (request.Properties.TryGetValue(HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name, out httpRequestMessageObject))
    {
        httpRequestMessage = httpRequestMessageObject as HttpRequestMessageProperty;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(httpRequestMessage.Headers[USER_AGENT_HTTP_HEADER]))
        {
            httpRequestMessage.Headers[USER_AGENT_HTTP_HEADER] = this.m_userAgent;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
        httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add(USER_AGENT_HTTP_HEADER, this.m_userAgent);
        request.Properties.Add(HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name, httpRequestMessage);
    }
    return null;
}
```

We could also use WebOperationContext to add http header on the client-side.
[Add Request header to WCF when using ConfigurationChannelFactory.CreateChannel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57034649/add-request-header-to-wcf-when-using-configurationchannelfactory-createchannel/57036736#57036736)
Please refer to the below discussion.
[How to add a custom HTTP header to every WCF call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964433/how-to-add-a-custom-http-header-to-every-wcf-call)
Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.